# Edit Presets in Calculate Mass

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

In the [documentation for Rigid Body physics](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/physics/rigid_body/properties.html) we are told "There are many useful presets available from the menu..." However, I find many of them are not so useful or are completely redundant. It's also very annoying that the custom value is at the bottom of an overly long list of these presets.

Is there an easy way to edit this list? (where easy means I don't have to recompile Blender)

[image]

Comment: Usually are Presets stored inside Blender app ... on PC /2.9x/scripts/presets/ (on Mac on right click Show Package /Contents/Resources/2.92/scripts/presets ), but I don't see any related to RB, so sadly not.

Comment: Search the scripts folder for “mass” or “density” and if nothing turns up, try turning on “file contents” and searching for some of the material names.

Comment: I grep'd the blender folder for 'Asphalt' and only found it in blender.exe and blender.pdb, so it looks like its hard-coded.